# Why is only the last component in array animating?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated

Goal: create an OptionFan button that when pressed, rotates on its Z axis, and FanItems release from behind the main button and travel along their own respective vectors.

OptionFan.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Image, View, Animated, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
import FanItem from './FanItem';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class OptionFan extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            animatedRotate: new Animated.Value(0),
            expanded: false
        };
    }

    handlePress = () => {
        if (this.state.expanded) {
            // button is opened
            Animated.spring(this.state.animatedRotate, {
                toValue: 0
            }).start();
            this.refs.option.collapse();
            this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
        } else {
            // button is collapsed
            Animated.spring(this.state.animatedRotate, {
                toValue: 1
            }).start();
            this.refs.option.expand();
            this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
        }
    };

    render () {
        const animatedRotation = this.state.animatedRotate.interpolate({
            inputRange: [ 0, 0.5, 1 ],
            outputRange: [ '0deg', '90deg', '180deg' ]
        });
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={{ position: 'absolute', left: 2, top: 2 }}>
                    {this.props.options.map((item, index) => (
                        <FanItem ref={'option'} icon={item.icon} onPress={item.onPress} index={index} />
                    ))}
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={() => this.handlePress()}>
                    <Animated.Image
                        resizeMode={'contain'}
                        source={require('./src/assets/img/arrow-up.png')}
                        style={{ transform: [ { rotateZ: animatedRotation } ], ...styles.icon }}
                    />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#E06363',
        elevation: 15,
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 3,
            width: 3
        },
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        height: width * 0.155,
        width: width * 0.155
    },
    icon: {
        height: width * 0.06,
        width: width * 0.06
    },
    optContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#219F75',
        elevation: 5,
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 3,
            width: 3
        },
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        height: width * 0.13,
        width: width * 0.13,
        position: 'absolute'
    }
});
```

FanItem.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Image, Animated, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import EStyleSheet from 'react-native-extended-stylesheet';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class FanItem extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            animatedOffset: new Animated.ValueXY(0),
            animatedOpacity: new Animated.Value(0)
        };
    }

    expand () {
        let offset = { x: 0, y: 0 };
        switch (this.props.index) {
            case 0:
                offset = { x: -50, y: 20 };
                break;
            case 1:
                offset = { x: -20, y: 50 };
                break;
            case 2:
                offset = { x: 20, y: 50 };
                break;
            case 3:
                offset = { x: 75, y: -20 };
                break;
        }
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.spring(this.state.animatedOffset, { toValue: offset }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.animatedOpacity, { toValue: 1, duration: 600 })
        ]).start();
    }

    collapse () {
        Animated.parallel([
            Animated.spring(this.state.animatedOffset, { toValue: 0 }),
            Animated.timing(this.state.animatedOpacity, { toValue: 0, duration: 600 })
        ]).start();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Animated.View
                style={
                    (this.props.style,
                    {
                        left: this.state.animatedOffset.x,
                        top: this.state.animatedOffset.y,
                        opacity: this.state.animatedOpacity
                    })
                }
            >
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container} onPress={this.props.onPress}>
                    <Image resizeMode={'contain'} source={this.props.icon} style={styles.icon} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
        );
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#219F75',
        elevation: 5,
        shadowOffset: {
            height: 3,
            width: 3
        },
        shadowColor: '#333',
        shadowOpacity: 0.5,
        shadowRadius: 5,
        height: width * 0.13,
        width: width * 0.13,
        position: 'absolute'
    },
    icon: {
        height: width * 0.08,
        width: width * 0.08
    }
});
```

Implementation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import Component from './Component';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const testArr = [
    {
        icon: require('./src/assets/img/chat.png'),
        onPress: () => alert('start chat')
    },
    {
        icon: require('./src/assets/img/white_video.png'),
        onPress: () => alert('video chat')
    },
    {
        icon: require('./src/assets/img/white_voice.png'),
        onPress: () => alert('voice chat')
    },
    {
        icon: require('./src/assets/img/camera.png'),
        onPress: () => alert('request selfie')
    }
];
const App = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.screen}>
            <Component options={testArr} />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#E6E6E6'
    }
});

export default App;
```

Problem: The issue is, only the last FanItem item runs its animation. (opacity, and vector translation). before implementing the opacity animation I could tell the first three FanItems did in fact render behind the main button, because I could see them when pressing the main button, as the opacity temporarily changes for the duration of the button click.

My question is 1) why are the first three mapped items not animating? and 2) how to resolve this?

Comment: can you provide a zip with the source code to test it ?

Comment: How do I add a zip file to a post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing `ref` of `FanItem` in `option`. but, `ref` gets overridden in each iteration of map. so, at the end it only stores `ref` of last `FanItem` in `option`. So, first declare one array in constructor to store `ref` of each `FanItem`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // your other code
    this.refOptions = [];
  }
```

Store `ref` of each `FanItem` separately like this:

```
{this.props.options.map((item, index) => (
    <FanItem ref={(ref) => this.refOptions[index] = ref} icon={item.icon} onPress={item.onPress} index={index} />
))}
```

and then to animate each `FanItem`:

```
for(var i = 0; i < this.refOptions.length; i++){
    this.refOptions[i].expand(); //call 'expand' or 'collapse' as required
}
```

This is expo snack link for your reference: 
https://snack.expo.io/BygobuL3JL